# Interface Ethernet voltage

Tags: voltage, current, ethernet, differential

I just want to know what are the voltage levels on the Ethernet differential lines (both single ended voltage level wrto ground & different voltage between the pairs). I haven't measured the signal and not able to get the right answer from internet search

This is the [PHY](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/00002245B.pdf) I am using.

Comment: For what you need them? You have the Ethernet standard? Are you talking about the PHY side or cable side of transformer? Most what you need are in the data sheet you linked so what are you missing?

Comment: What's "wrto"? With regard to?

Comment: Wikipedia lists it as: ± 2.5 V (over twisted pair). So that's votlage between the lines. Votlage with respect to ground depends on how you define and connect ground.

Comment: Ethernet wires are isolated from ground hence there is no specification other than that implied by any impulse withstand testing.

Comment: @Justme, I just want to understand how to signals would be. Like what would the voltage levels. On the Cable side of the ethernet phy/transformer. Basically Tx and Rx differential pair signals.

Comment: @winny, just want to understand the voltage levels of the tx and rx signals, in single ended measurement as well as differential level measurement

Comment: @Andyaka, just want to understand the level of voltage that will be present on the ethernet cable

Comment: The voltages are in the data sheet.

Comment: @Justme, thank you. So, I saw the peak differential output is 0.95V to 1.05V for 100Mbps. This voltage is measured across the Tx+ and Tx- across the pins right? Can you tell me what would be the voltage between Tx+ and Gnd and Tx- and Gnd? Just curious to know. The datasheet doesn't mention that.

Comment: As has already been stated, the lines are isolated from ground. There is no meaningful value of voltage between TX+ and Gnd as there's no circuit for current to flow in.

Comment: That didn't answer my question.

Comment: @Finbarr, what about the voltage on the PHY pins. Tx+ and Tx- pins. The PHY is referenced to the board ground right?

Comment: The common mode voltage on the PHY output pins isn't defined in the datasheet but given that it's powered from 3.3 V and 0V you can safely assume it's somewhere in between the two.

Comment: @Finbarr, oh so the CM voltage for the Tx+ and Tx- pins would be between 0V and 3.3V. The differential voltage between the Tx+ and Tx- pins is 1V for 100Base and 2.5V for 10Base, Is my understanding correct? Please let me know. Just curious to know is it the same differential voltage for 1000Base? Why are the voltage levels different for different speeds?

Comment: @Finbarr, 1. Since the absolute maximum rating on the PHY pins are 4V, I am just trying to understand The peak voltage on Tx+ for 10BaseT. It would be 3.3 + (2.5V/2) = 3.3V + 1.25V = 4.25V, right? Which violates the stress levels of the pin right?

Comment: No. The PHY will be unable to drive the TX pins higher than its supply voltage.

Comment: @Finbarr, the what would be the single ended voltage on the Tx pin and ground for 10Base T? Because 10Base is 2.5V differential right?

Comment: Same answer as before. The common mode voltage will be somewhere between 0 and 3.3 Volts. Given that all the outputs do is drive a transformer it really doesn't matter as long as the correct differential output levels are correct.